# How to include ssl_module to Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, openssl

As in my centos 7 `httpd.conf`,I include `ssl_module` as `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`.
But I get error as below:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 71 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I run `yum install openssl`,I got `Package 1:openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version Nothing to do.`
Then I  run `whereis openssl`, I got
`openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz`
How to  include ssl_module to Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the documentation of your OperatingSystem?

The configuration for mod_ssl is in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Comment: in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`,only `autoindex.conf  php.conf  README  userdir.conf  welcome.conf`

Comment: ssl.conf is not present anymore by default

Answer (score 6):

Just execute

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

to install the module if not present

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the file `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so` exists by

```
ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

and put the result by editing your question.

Plus, if your httpd process is running under the apache user (or other non-root user), verify that the `/etc/httpd` directory, and all its files and sub-directories, has the proper rights.

Comment: ls: cannot access /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

To configure mod_ssl with apache httpd you need to follow these steps :

*Machine Details ($ hostnamectl) :*

```
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
  CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
  Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

*Apache Version ($ httpd -V):*

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   May 30 2023 14:01:11
```

---

1. Installing mod_ssl :
   `yum install -y mod_ssl`
2. Create encrypted private key , you can also add passphrase :
   `openssl genrsa -aes128 -out your-key-path/httpdkey.pem`
3. Generate a self-signed certificate using the encrypted private key : `openssl req -new -x509 -key your-key-path/httpdkey.pem -out certs/httpdcert.pem -days 365` 
   fill the required information like passphrase and address , common name , email etc.

> first we created private key , now 2nd command generate a self-signed certificate that corresponds to the private key. The combination of the private key and the certificate forms a basic security setup, often used for testing and development purposes. In a production environment,we should obtain a certificate from a trusted certificate authority (CA) instead of using a self-signed certificate , Amazon ACM provides free SSl Certs.

4. Update the cert path in apache config file :
   `vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
   and add these :

   ```
   ServerName your-domain.com:443
   SSLCertificateFile /your/path/to/certs/httpdcert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /your/path/to/cert/httpdkey.pem
   ```
5. restart httpd, add 443 port in firewall, restart firewall :

```
systemctl restart httpd
firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: You can use `openssl s_client -connect  your-domain.com:443`  to verify the ssl setup.